# What color code is it in \textcolor? How can I get the same color as text?

Tags: color, packages

[image]

What color is this? I tried `\textcolor{orange}{text}` but it gives slightly lighter color. How can I get similar color as the above image text `provably efficient exploration` and `function approximation`?

Answer (score 2):

Using a color picking tool of your choice you can obtain the RGB values corresponding to the text color. Using `xcolor` you can then define this color with the previously obtained RGB values and use it later on:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{221,110,78}

\begin{document}

text \textcolor{myorange}{orange text} text

\end{document}
```